# plt.add_patch causes an error, how do I add a rectangle over a set of points?

Tags: python, matplotlib

All of my attempts failed. I tried to draw rectangle over set of points with pyplot but I keep getting different errors. Can someone help? I need to add rectangle of size width = 4 and height= 2sqrt(3)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

def main():
    print("hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = []
    y = []

    for k in range(30):
      for l in range(30):
        x.append(4*k + 2*(l % 2))
        y.append(2*l*3**(1/2))

    rect = patches.Rectangle((0,0),4,2*3**(1/2),linewidth=1,edgecolor='b',facecolor='none') 
    plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
    plt.axis([0, 10, 0, 10])


    #plt.add_patch(rect)

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Instead of saying "I keep getting different errors", edit your question to include the actual error (with traceback) that goes with the code you've pasted. There's usually important information in there—and even if you can't tell what it means, one of the people helping you may be able to. This is part of creating a [mcve]. (You've done the other parts very well—this is a great minimal code example—but it may still be worth reading that help page.)

Comment: Your for loop is not indented

Comment: @abarnert I tried multiple things of everything. should I post all of it? I am new to matplotlib... so I messed with many things. E.g I commented out plt.add_patch(rect). But I tried tons of other things. adding subplots.. etc.

Comment: http://matthiaseisen.com/pp/patterns/p0203/ have you looked at this? Try starting from these examples and modify them to your needs

Comment: You don't need to post everything. Just post one example, and the errors you got (and, if it's not obvious, how you wanted that example to work). There's a good chance we can show you how to fix that exact example to do what you wanted (or at least get you in the direction of what you wanted). If not, we can ask followup questions.

Comment: Why aren't you just use y1 = y0, y2 = y0+2*np.sqrt(3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add_patch` is an `axes` method, not something directly under `pyplot`. Just change your commented line to:

```
plt.gca().add_patch(rect)
```

`gca()` gets the current active axes in pyplot.

Comment: THANK YOUUUU! really helped